# How to use Tailwind CSS default color variable in custom classes?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I just want to use tailwind css default colors in my custom css classes. For eg.

```
li.active{
    color: var(--colors-red-50);/* from tailwind css color palette*/
}
```

I am using tailwind css with next js.

Comment: `@apply text-red-50;`

Comment: This work for me. Thanks. `li.active{ @apply text-red-50; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this is `index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  li.active {
    @apply text-red-50; 
  }
}
```